# Changing Color of LinkButton in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, linkbutton

I am creating a custom pagination for my GridView, so far I've done everything except this thing: I want to highlight the selected page in different color or different font style or anything I want to. For example if I have pages 1 2 3 4 5 6 and I do select 4, when it reloads the data from GridView I want 4 to be colored in Red 1 2 3 **4** 5 6.
This is my aspx file

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterPaging" runat="server" >
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="pagingLinkButton" runat="server"
        Text='<%#Eval("Text") +" | " %>' 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
        Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled")%>' 
        OnClick="linkButton_Click" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="false">
    </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

If u can give me any info about how can I put "  |  " away, so only the numbers be like LinkButtons, since now my LinkButton is NUMBER+" | "

My LinkButtonClick method

```
        protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int totalRows = 0;
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
        lb.Attributes.Add("class", "BlackLnkBtn");
        int pageIndex = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        pageIndex -= 1;
        gridViewSearchReport.PageIndex = pageIndex;
        //gridViewSearchReport.DataSource = EmployeeDataAccessLayer.
        //    GetEmployees(pageIndex, GridView1.PageSize, out totalRows);
       // FetchData(pageIndex);

        gridViewSearchReport.DataSource = FetchData(pageIndex+1);
        gridViewSearchReport.DataBind();
        DatabindRepeater(pageIndex, gridViewSearchReport.PageSize, RowNumber());
        CheckButtonsAvailability(pageIndex + 1);

    }
```

and im filling the page like this

```
pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(),i.ToString(), i != (pageIndex + 1)));
```

Basicly I want to indicate which is the current page I am viewing atm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each time you rebind the repeater through DatabindRepeater(), you overwrite the css change you make. You should consider not to rebind the repeater in linkButton's click event. Post the code for DatabindRepeater method, someone should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in a different way, using javascript : I added this function so a hidden label can take the value of the selected index, and then the selected index take the style of this label.

```
        $().ready(function () {
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbPageView(THIS IS DIV ID OF THE ROW WHERE PAGINATION IS GENERATING>a').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == $('.lblPageNum').text())  
            {
                $(this).css('color', '#FDBE0E');
            }
        });
    });
```

label:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblPageNum" style="display:none;" Class="lblPageNum" runat="server" />
```

and then simply change it in code-behind in the btnclick event

```
lblPageNum.Text = (pageIndex += 1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ForeColor` property of the `LinkButton` in the click handler, like this:

```
protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //int totalRows = 0;
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    lb.Attributes.Add("class", "BlackLnkBtn");
    int pageIndex = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    pageIndex -= 1;
    gridViewSearchReport.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    //gridViewSearchReport.DataSource = EmployeeDataAccessLayer.
    //    GetEmployees(pageIndex, GridView1.PageSize, out totalRows);
   // FetchData(pageIndex);

    gridViewSearchReport.DataSource = FetchData(pageIndex+1);
    gridViewSearchReport.DataBind();
    DatabindRepeater(pageIndex, gridViewSearchReport.PageSize, RowNumber());
    CheckButtonsAvailability(pageIndex + 1);

    // Make the clicked link button red
    lb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: yeah...I already did that and it doesn't help :/ If you need any further information/code which can cause this issue please tell me.